# Flatpak: Cannot run application, exit code 159

Tags: linux, debian

I have installed [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) recently on my Debian Testing System (current Buster)
and now tried to install [DeltaChat](https://flathub.org/apps/details/chat.delta.desktop). But after a successful installation I cannot launch the app,
instead Flatpak returns 159 as exit code.
I have also tried to run [Spotify](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.spotify.Client) or [VS Code OSS](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.visualstudio.code.oss) with the same result.
I also tried to install the apps in system (without `--user`) instead of user giving the same result.

With verbose enabled, Flatpak does also not really indicate why it is crashing:

```
$ flatpak --user -v run chat.delta.desktop; echo $?
F: Opening user flatpak installation at path /home/zocker/.local/share/flatpak
F: Opening user flatpak installation at path /home/zocker/.local/share/flatpak
F: No installations directory in /etc/flatpak/installations.d. Skipping
F: Opening user flatpak installation at path /home/zocker/.local/share/flatpak
F: Opening system flatpak installation at path /var/lib/flatpak
F: Cleaning up unused container id 1289461851
F: Allocated instance id 3320985649
F: Add defaults in dir /chat/delta/desktop/
F: Add locks in dir /chat/delta/desktop/
F: Allowing dri access
F: Allowing homedir access
F: Allowing x11 access
F: Allowing pulseaudio access
F: Pulseaudio user configuration file '/home/zocker/.config/pulse/client.conf': Fehler beim Öffnen der Datei »/home/zocker/.config/pulse/client.conf«: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
F: Running 'bwrap --args 30 xdg-dbus-proxy --args=32'
F: Running 'bwrap --args 30 /app/bin/run.sh'
159
```

The missing pulseaudio configuration file is not the reason I think
because Flatpak continues to launch the apps and
`touch ~/.config/pulse/client.conf` causes only this single line to disappear.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: After you installed, did you log out and log in again?

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for your suggestion, but even a full system reboot does not change anything.